# where to download SVN for Mac OSX 10.4.11?

Tags: svn, macos, download

I'm having a lot of trouble finding SVN for Mac OS X 10.4.11. Would someone please point me to the binary I can download? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

At present, the publicly available SVN binary installers are all geared towards 10.5+.

What that means for you is that you will need to get comfortable with the terminal. I've installed subversion with both Fink and MacPorts before ([as indicated on subversion's own site](http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html#osx)). Alternatively, you can download the source and build it yourself ([here's a slightly dated tutorial from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/tools/subversionxcode.html)).

Alternatively, you could use a GUI SVN application like Versions or a text editor like TextMate that has built-in SVN support as a more user-friendly alternative to the Terminal.

Comment: I installed Fink and downloaded the svn-client, but it won't let me install the svn-slient-ssl which I need to access my project on Google Project Hosting. Fink seems to think that the svn-client-ssl is already installed, but when I use svn import it says "svn: SSL not supported". Would you please help me out with this?

Answer (score 1):

For 10.4, it's a little tough.

To start, I would try a stable binary from [CollabNet](http://svnbinaries.open.collab.net/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?folderID=164&expandFolder=164&folderID=171).

If that link fails to work, you may try a binary from the [Fink Package Database](http://pdb.finkproject.org/pdb/package.php/svn?rel_id=10.4-i386-0.8.1-bindist) using [Fink](http://www.finkproject.org/download/index.php?phpLang=en).

Comment: I installed Fink and downloaded the svn-client, but it won't let me install the svn-slient-ssl which I need to access my project on Google Project Hosting. Fink seems to think that the svn-client-ssl is already installed, but when I use svn import it says "svn: SSL not supported". Would you please help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

Neither Fink or MacPorts seem to host 10.4 anymore ?

I googled subversion-client-1.3.1.dmg
and found http://ubc.fay.ar.us/pub/subversion/1.3.2/macosx/

Installer puts it in /usr/local/bin/svn*

$2c,
*-pike